# Why didn't Lily James dye her eyebrows to match her hair?

Tags: make-up, cinderella-2015

I just saw Disney's 2015 *Cinderella*.  Not a cheaply made movie, but the lead actress (naturally a brunette), whose character is supposed to be blonde, did not have her eyebrows dyed like she did her hair.

I discussed the question with a beautician who said that dying eyebrows can be a little more tricky than dying hair, but still pretty straightforward.  She said the typical reason people with dark hair don't dye their eyebrows is that they look strange when they grow in with dark roots (in a way that hair doesn't).  But obviously, for film, hair-and-makeup keeps the actors' hair dyed so root color doesn't appear, so they could just as readily keep up with eyebrows.

Here's the star, [Lily James](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm4066896128/nm4141252?ref_=nmmi_mi_all_evt_1), eyebrows not dyed:

[image: Cinderella undyed eyebrows]

And, strangely, here's the brunette actress [Hayley Atwell](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2017943/?ref_=tt_cl_t11) playing the brief part of her mother *with* eyebrows dyed to match her hair:

[image]

Comment: Eyebrows don't typically have to match the hair. Most blondes, even natural ones don't have the same shade eyebrows.

Comment: @cde - Perhaps you could show some examples?  Certainly the *shade* could vary, but I don't believe I have ever seen naturally dark brown eyebrows on a person with naturally light blond hair.

Comment: A Google image search of **Blonde Eyebrows** shows a lot.

Comment: @cde - Indeed: I see [natural blondes whose eyebrows are as light as their hair](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2128447/Find-YOUR-eyebrow-tribe-Kate-Posh-brows-big-news-ANNABEL-JONES-shows-ways-shape-up.html), some with darker eyebrows, and then [people with naturally dark hair](http://www.vulture.com/2013/05/great-moments-in-blonde-hair-dark-eyebrows/slideshow/) sporting [dark (undyed) eyebrows and dyed light hair](https://maidenheadbeauty.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/blonde-eyebrow-anxiety/).

Comment: This question would be a lot more interesting if you named the actress and included a screen grab of this ..travesty(?)

Comment: An example which always bothers me is Emilia Clarke playing Daenerys Targaryen in Game Of Thrones.

Comment: @franz xaver : Emilia wears a wig when playing daenerys.i guess it would look very strange when she puts of the wig after shooting but has blond dyed eyebrowd

Comment: @kl78 - Another note from the beautician: It's easy to darken light eyebrows with pencil.  So if she were really committed to the part she would bleach the eyebrows to match and then if it bothered her off-set use makeup until she decided to more permanently dye her eyebrows back.

Comment: "if she were really committed to the part" I'd don't think color-of-hair is or needs to be a primary aspect of 'commitment to a part'.

Comment: ... not to mention that a lot of natural blondes darken their eyebrows to have more dramatic effect... with blonde eyebrows, they can sometimes blend into your face color, so you look like you don't have eyebrows at all.... which is [creepy](http://glamyhair.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Natural-Blonde-Straight-Hairstyles-For-Women-From-Caroline-Winberg1.jpeg).

Comment: @Catija - Good point.  So, in this case, I guess either (1) we are to believe Cinderalla *the character* darkens her eyebrows out of uncharacteristic vanity, or (2) Cinderalla *the character* is a natural blonde with extraordinarily naturally dark eyebrows, or (3) the actress and/or hair-and-makeup didn't think that detail was worth addressing in a $100MM reproduction of a Disney cartoon about a blonde protagonist (with blonde eyebrows)?  Hard to suspend disbelief with so many questions ;)

Comment: ... Um... Seriously? Most people don't care.... her eyebrows are barely darker than her hair in that photo you've posted... it's a movie... not reality. Get over it.

Comment: I agree that screen grab doesn't show the contrast as strikingly as many of the movie's scenes.  I just posted one showing it more clearly.  Because it's a high-budget film, not reality, so I can't believe they couldn't be bothered with a cosmetic detail like that that's staring us in the face the entire time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the aim was to try to remain as true to the Disney original artwork as possible. Note that in the 1951 Cinderella, our eponymous heroine has dark eyebrows to go along with her strawberry-blond hair

[image]

And even the earliest concept art for the 2015 film (drawn *before* an actress was selected) has Cinders with brown eyebrows...

[image]